# How to clear(onclick backspace) the TextInput that I was made for month expiry pattern in react native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I had created a TextInput which is formatted in the pattern like as the credit card month expiry date like as 'MM/YY'.

But got issue when to clear the textinput value. Below is the video you can see the issue of it.
[Click here to see the video of the issue](https://somup.com/c3iu6du4wK)

Below is the full expo code link, for ease of the making and solving the issue. Issue is, I can't clear the '/' as you can see in the video. [click here to go to the full code - expo link](https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/uplifting-orange)

Answer (score 0):

I see you want custom integration without using any library and here is [example](https://snack.expo.dev/NKym6jI7A) with copied component from the react-native-mask-input that does the job perfectly by giving masking expression.